Implementing a FIFO allocation between two lists in Python
I am trying to write an algorithm in Python to link quantities in a FIFO fashion between two different series (of length N). The input is two lists, 'instructions' and 'responses'.
The two lists represent signed integer values of two time series, the first of which encodes an instruction (e.g. move some distance), while the second represents the actions of the responder to the received instructions. The responder always intends to match the system target (instructions' cumulative sum), and in general falls short on the first iteration; however over enough steps, the responder eventually catches up. In some cases it may 'overshoot' the target, whether that be 'too positive', or 'too negative'.
The goal of the algorithm is to distinguish what quantity of each response belongs to the current instruction, and what quantity belongs to an earlier instruction (and then link this quantity to the original instruction index). The intended output is in an allocation matrix of size (NxN), which describes how the quantities of each response are to be allocated to each instruction. The matrix is naturally lower-triangular (as response quantities cannot be allocated to future instructions).
For example, consider the series:
import pandas as pd
instructions = [100, 50, 20, 0, -50, -100]
responses = [80, 40, 10, 40, -20, -130]
df = pd.DataFrame({'instructions': instructions,
                   'responses': responses})

By plotting the cumulative sums, one can visualise the trajectory of the target and realised positions. The response series catches up with the instructions after step 3 and again after step 5.

In terms of allocation we can see:

At step 0, all of the 80 should be linked to the instruction, leaving 20 remaining
At step 1, 20 of the total 40 should be linked to the instruction at step 0 (and the other 20 should be linked to the instruction at step 1)
At step 2, all of the total 10 should be linked to the instruction at step 1 (which is still unrealised)
At step 3, 20 of the total 40 should be linked to the instruction at step 1, and the other 20 should be linked to the instruction at step 2. The response series has caught up with the target at this point.
At step 4, all of the total -20 is allocated to step 4, leaving -30 to go
At step 5, -30 of the total -130 is allocated to the previous step, and -100 is allocated to step 5, bringing the responder back in line

This is encoded in the allocation matrix like:




0
1
2
3
4
5




0
80
0
0
0
0
0


1
20
20
0
0
0
0


2
0
10
0
0
0
0


3
0
20
20
0
0
0


4
0
0
0
0
-20
0


5
0
0
0
0
-30
-100



I have approached this as below, but this doesn't capture all the possible edge cases. I am particularly concerned by how to handle:

If the response overshoots the target
If the position crosses zero and / or signs are flipped
If the target moves closer to zero before the response catches up, so there is 'too much' to allocate. In this case I believe I need to add dummy quantities to ensure the responder has moved the same total quantity (absolute cumsum?) as the instructor, but unsure where/how to do this.


import numpy as np
def allocate_responses(instructions, responses):
    n = len(instructions)
    allocation_matrix = np.zeros((n,n))
    
    # Loop over the lower-triangular elements of the allocation matrix
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i + 1):
            if instructions[j] == 0 or responses[i] == 0:
                continue
            
            # Initialise the allocation amount as the lesser of the instruction or the response
            allocation_amount = min(abs(instructions[j]), abs(responses[i]))
            
            # Assuming the instructor has not turned back on itself before the responder caught up:
            if instructions[j] > 0 and responses[i] > 0:
                allocation_matrix[i][j] += allocation_amount
                instructions[j] -= allocation_amount
                responses[i] -= allocation_amount
            
            # Same but instructions went negative
            elif instructions[j] < 0 and responses[i] < 0:
                allocation_matrix[i][j] -= allocation_amount
                instructions[j] += allocation_amount
                responses[i] += allocation_amount

    return allocation_matrix



What modifications are required for this function to handle all possible series of instruction and response?
If we add a constraint that the sum of positive instruction quantities equals the sun of positive response quantities (and the same for negative quantities), is the solution much simpler to implement?
Is there a simpler way of storing state (e.g. in a series of NxN
matrices) and solving this using matrix operations without a nested
loop, that can handle the edge cases?


Can't think of anything. Same thing. Look into NetworkX, but still you might end up doing it with same time complexity.

Thanks - the complexity is less of a concern to me than it actually working for all inputs. If it can only be done using nested loops that is acceptable too. Is it simpler if we add a constraint that the total in and total out quantities are guaranteed to be the same? If so, can a standard FIFO algorithm be used to simplify the implementation?

I think it would help if you finalize the description of expected output. To me, the few edge cases look problematic mostly because there are several possible ways to fill the matrix, and the question is not clear on which one to choose.

Example 1: overshoot. Instruction A: target went to 0 -> 20. Then Response went to 0 -> 30. Where to allocate the extra 10, they just burn and get nowhere? The next Response is 30 -> 20. Where to allocate this compensating -10, they just burn and get nowhere? Sometime (before or after second response) happens Instruction B: target went back, 20 -> 0. For the first -10 after the extra 10, do they get burned first, or do they fill Instruction B first if it already happened?

Example 2: too slow response. Instruction A: target went to 0 -> 20. Instruction B: target went to 20 -> 10. Instruction C: target went to 10 -> 30. Only then Response went 0 -> 30 at once. The first 20 fill Instruction A. What about the other 10. They don't get to fill Instruction C until we have explicit -10 for Instruction B, right? So, they are an overshot, right?

Thanks for your helpful comments. Yes those are the edge cases I would like to handle. The first example, overshoot is allocated on the same day, so the solution is a matrix like diag(30, -10, -20). The second example, the instruction in step 2 partially cancels the outstanding instruction in step 1: so the solution is a matrix with zeros except the bottom row; the bottom row contains [10, 0, 20].

An alternative to example 2 could involve adding synthetic movements to the responder to simulate the partial cancellation of the instructions. E.g. then the matrix would look like [[10,0,0],[0,-10,0],[10,0,20]]. I am not sure which solution is the best but I would be happy with whichever works.
